# Facebook Android SDK v4.0.0 ShareDialog NullPointerException issue

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

As per these instructions https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android I have implemented the Facebook ShareDialog to appear in my app but it's causing the following error.

> 03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275): Process: au.com.elegantmedia.emotit, PID: 10275
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:746)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at com.facebook.internal.Utility.getDialogFeatureConfig(Utility.java:859)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at com.facebook.internal.DialogPresenter.getVersionSpecForFeature(DialogPresenter.java:248)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at com.facebook.internal.DialogPresenter.getProtocolVersionForNativeDialog(DialogPresenter.java:234)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at com.facebook.internal.DialogPresenter.canPresentNativeDialogWithFeature(DialogPresenter.java:75)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog.canShowNative(ShareDialog.java:133)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog.access$0(ShareDialog.java:130)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog$NativeHandler.canShow(ShareDialog.java:241)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at com.facebook.share.widget.ShareDialog$NativeHandler.canShow(ShareDialog.java:1)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at com.facebook.internal.FacebookDialogBase.createAppCallForMode(FacebookDialogBase.java:184)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at com.facebook.internal.FacebookDialogBase.showImpl(FacebookDialogBase.java:147)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at com.facebook.internal.FacebookDialogBase.show(FacebookDialogBase.java:142)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at au.com.elegantmedia.emotit.activities.MainActivity.onTellAFriendClick(MainActivity.java:299)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at au.com.elegantmedia.emotit.activities.MainActivity.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:194)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1143)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3044)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3833)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>   03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

At line,

> 03-27 16:12:53.150: E/AndroidRuntime(10275):  at com.facebook.internal.Utility.getDialogFeatureConfig(Utility.java:859)

is the following piece of code,

```
FetchedAppSettings settings = fetchedAppSettings.get(applicationId);
```

Both `fetchedAppSettings` - `{}` and `applicationId` - `null` seems to be not initialised.

The only place the applicationId is, is in the manifest file.

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderXXX"
      android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
      android:exported="true"/>
```

XXX being the applicationId and I have put it there correctly. Everything else also done such as,

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    callBackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    shareDialog.registerCallback(callBackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Result result) {
            ELog.d(LOG_TAG, "success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            ELog.d(LOG_TAG, "error");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            ELog.d(LOG_TAG, "cancel");
        }
    });
```

in `onCreate()` and calling,

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
                .setContentDescription(
                        "The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
                .setContentUrl(
                        Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfa1/t39.2178-6/11057086_1577191859234204_214246289_n.png"))
                .build();

        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
    }
```

when user clicks to share content. Is there something that I have missed? Or am I running into some sort of a bug in the new SDK which causes the `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You also need to add the application id like this:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ...>
  ...
  <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"  android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
  ...
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks Gokhan. I actually missed two things. What you mentioned above and the following. "<activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>" I know, coming from previous versions these things need to be there but it's a shame it's not mentioned in the link I provided in my question. I'm actually trying to integrate Facebook SDK into an Android app after ages.

Comment: You're right, @JanithaR, I'll make sure that documentation is updated, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Gokhan Caglar I am on the same timethief for +24hours. I have followed the mentioned link and updated according to your comment. Still I get the same nullpointer exception. Could there be other reasons for this error?

Comment: @carl Did you go through: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/ Can you see what's null  in the debugger?

Comment: I have another app working well with development keyhash, etc,and have triple checked to my best effort. Thus very strange. In trouble app, I try: FacebookSdk.isInitialized() = true, I try FacebookSdk.getApplicationId()= null, and same for .getApplicationName()=null. Seems FB does not find the application definition at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/xxxxx. Are there any known vulnerabilities that you are aware of, e.g. Android target/minimum or similar? I have also tried to delete and redefine the app at said link, no change. The other app is using sdk3.7. I am using Netbeans

Comment: If the application id is null, then you must have an issue with the way you defined it in the AndroidManifest.xml file. The name is also set in the manifest as meta-data in the application tag, look here for an example: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/Scrumptious/AndroidManifest.xml#L51-L52

Comment: Thanks man, helped me out. Take my upvote because you made my day :)

Answer (score 19):

(hopefully someone at FB will read this)

In addition to the (correct) advice given by Gokhan Caglar, also note this: Do not write the app-id number directly into AndroidManifest.xml!  For FB to work, app-id must also be defined properly according to best practice in the file strings.xml

Because the app-id is also used under the provider tag, but there directly as the number, I did the shortcut of writing the app-id number directly into the meta-data tag as well. Huge mistake, 2 days gone.

As it seems, FB will make use of app-id fetched from both AndroidManifest.xml and directly based on the definitions in strings.xml. Both must be there. app-id must be defined in strings.xml. This solved the issue.

For FB development team, a couple of suggestions that will save people’s time:

- Either remove this over-stringent use of app-id, or explain in the tutorial that this is the only way. (It is more stringent than Android itself)
- Make a better error reporting system as overlay when the app definitions are not proper. A null exception like this deep within FB soon becomes your time thief of the day. In this case, an error report of the type:  ”Error: app-id not defined in strings.xml” would have been satisfactory.
- Regarding the tutorial, it contains a trap also, and so I mention it: If you run the tutorial here: https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=android, after you have already inserted key hash for development, something you would easily do if things aren’t working, then be aware that this tutorial will delete (or rather replace) vital info in the app definition without telling you about it. Since you have perhaps already defined the keyhash, you do not fill it in once again in this quickstart guide. Hence, later you discover that the keyhash is gone and wonder why.

Comment: Spent most of today trying to implement the Facebook SDK, countless bugs. (I even hit the 64k method limit in android). I hope they rewrite it (or get better developers) cause at the moment the facebook sdk is utter crap-ware.

Comment: I wouldn't have noticed this in a million year. Thanks!

Wtf facebook?

Comment: I'm having problems (clicked Share and nothing happened) and it turns out the Key Hash was missing in my App settings! To fix it you need to go to Facebook developer page > My Apps > Select the app > Settings and check if the Key Hash is still there.
It didn't fix the problem but at least now I know that the Key Hash isn't gone.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank. i had the app Id directly in meta tag causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand how that makes a difference besides best practice, i would think the string converts at run time anyway... but thanks was about to waste more hours :)

Comment: Carl, thank you! You saved me. I wonder always how facebook could become successful with such a bunch of bugs, so called facebook SDK.

Comment: Wow, that is such an oversight. Nowhere in the getting started guide does it say this!

Answer (score 1):

do not write the facebook key within the meta

write it in a string and reference it in the meta in manifest

like so

```
<string name="id_facebook">id_facebook</string>

<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/id_facebook" />
```

hope this helps :)