# Facebook login crashes for app-release.apk

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, google-signin

I integrated Google signin and Facebook login to my app. Everything works fine in debug mode, but in release mode it crashes.

```
    04-30 11:15:12.113 28773-28788/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                                               Process: com.cs442.Team14, PID: 28773
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:772)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:800)
                                                   at com.facebook.internal.Utility.queryAppSettings(Utility.java:846)
                                                   at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$1.run(LoginButton.java:491)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I have already added the Application ID in my Manifest file.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value= "XXXXXXXXX"/>
```

(Since I support multiple languages, I was getting an error if I used @string/facebook_app_id. So instead I directly pasted the number instead)

So here is the steps I have followed so far:

1. Created project on Google and Facebook developer sites
2. Added respective debug and release keys at the developer site
3. Generated keystore file for my app, put the keys in it (i.e keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias  -keystore \.keystore, keytool -exportcert -alias  -keystore \GoShop.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64)
4. Generated signed apk from Android Studio: Build -> Generate signed APK -> used the above keystore file

What am I missing?

Comment: android:value= "XXXXXXXXX" you directly assigin value?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298996/facebook-android-sdk-v4-0-0-sharedialog-nullpointerexception-issue

Comment: XXXXX = Facebook app ID

Comment: I have the string reference of my app id in strings.xml as well. I can't use @string/facebook_app_id because I get this error: Error:(24) Error: Resources referenced from the manifest cannot vary by configuration (except for version qualifiers, e.g. -v21.) Found variation in de [ManifestResource]
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value= "@string/facebook_app_id"/> (I am supporting enand de languages)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the problem was all about "not" using a string reference from strings.xml! Since I'm supporting 2 languages, I have 2 strings.xml (en, de) files. There are 2 issues here: 1) in the manifest file, the meta-data tag 'must' use @atring/facebook_app_id 2) Now, since there are multiple strings.xml, if I used the string reference it gives this error: Resources referenced from the manifest cannot vary by configuration (except for version qualifiers, e.g. -v21.) Found variation in de [ManifestResource]  (This is ridiculous)

If I directly use the App Id number for meta-data, the app crashes (release variant only. debug variant works fine). When I removed the strings.xml file for de, it worked fine!. I hope the Facebook SDK team really looks into such ridiculous issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `translatable="false"` on string value of strings.xml resource file.

In the other strings.xml resources (strings-pt.xml, strings.de-xml, etc) must not have the selected string variable.